# Eigen Indices of Dense Matrix meeting Condition

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm looking to get the row/column indices from a dense matrix which meet a condition. In my case the result is likely to be very sparse. For example, with matrix

```
1 5 2
7 6 3
2 3 8
```

I'd like to get the indicies where the coeff is greater than 4, or

```
(0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (2,2)
```

My initial thoughts include using either [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654840/eigen-mask-an-array) or [coefficientwise](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) operations to build a bool/int matrix

```
0 1 0
1 1 0
0 0 1
```

and then convert it to a sparse matrix

```
(0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,1), (2,2,1)
```

then remove the coeff values

```
(0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (2,2)
```

However, that requires two passes over matrices the size of the original matrix, which may be very large.

Alternatively a naive double loop over the original matrix akin to pseudocode

```
for (int i; i < mat.cols(); i++) {
    for (int j; j < mat.rows(); j++) {
        if(cond(mat(j, i))) {
            add_index(i, j, index_list)
        }
    }
}
```

but that only takes the compilers optimizations and none of Eigen's optimizations/vectorizations.

Is there a more efficient way that I am missing? In my case the conditions are simple comparisons.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much to vectorize here, but to avoid writing the two loops (which might better be reversed for a row-major storage), the best tool would be a visitor:

```
mat.visit(some_visitor);
```

Sadly, the visitor cannot be a simple lambda as `visit` calls the method `init(val,0,0)` for the first element. This is useful for reduction-like visitors but not always. In order to make `visit` accepts a simple lambda, you can use the following helper:

```
template<typename Func>
struct lambda_as_visitor_wrapper : Func {
    lambda_as_visitor_wrapper(const Func& f) : Func(f) {}
    template<typename S,typename I>
    void init(const S& v, I i, I j) { return Func::operator()(v,i,j); }
};

template<typename Mat, typename Func>
void visit_lambda(const Mat& m, const Func& f)
{
    lambda_as_visitor_wrapper<Func> visitor(f);
    m.visit(visitor);
}
```

In your case, you can then write:

```
int main() {
    int n = 5;
    double th = 0.5;
    Eigen::MatrixXd M = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(n,n);

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> indices;
    visit_lambda(M,
        [&indices,th](double v, int i, int j) {
            if(v>th)
                indices.push_back(std::make_pair(i,j));
        });


    std::cout << M << "\n\n";

    for(auto p:indices)
        std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ") ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great. _There is not much to vectorize here, but to avoid writing the two loops (which might better be reversed for a row-major storage)_ I was under the impression Eigen was column-major by default, is this not the case?

Comment: Yes it is column-major by default, but if you want to write generic code taking arbitrary expressions as input, this might not always be the case.