# More efficient way to get indices of a binary mask in Eigen3?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I currently have a bool mask vector generated in Eigen. I would like to use this binary mask similar as in Python `numpy`, where depending on the `True` value, i get a sub-matrix or a sub-vector, where i can further do some calculations on these.

To achieve this in Eigen, i currently "convert" the mask vector into another vector containing the indices by simply iterating over the mask:

```
Eigen::Array<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> mask = ... // E.G.: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];

Eigen::Array<uint32_t, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> mask_idcs(mask.count(), 1);
int z_idx = 0;
for (int z = 0; z < mask.rows(); z++) {
    if (mask(z)) {
        mask_idcs(z_idx++) = z;
     }
}
// do further calculations on vector(mask_idcs)
// E.G.:    vector(mask_idcs)*3 + another_vector
```

However, i want to further optimize this and am wondering if Eigen3 provides a more elegant solution for this, something like `vector(from_bin_mask(mask))`, which may benefit from the libraries optimization.

There are already some questions here in SO, but none seems to answer this simple use-case
([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253415/eigen-boolean-array-slicing), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654840/eigen-mask-an-array)). Some refer to the `select`-function, which returns an equally sized vector/matrix/array, but i want to discard elements via a mask and only work further with a smaller vector/matrix/array.

Is there a way to do this in a more elegant way? Can this be optimized otherwise?

(I am using the `Eigen::Array`-type since most of the calculations are element-wise in my use-case)

Comment: Not sure if this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). If all you want is using boolean masks to slice a vector you can easily write your own slicing as shown at the very bottom of [this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html).

Comment: But i think this could be slow. Lets say, we would have an mask with alternating 0 and 1, then we would need to slice the a vector vector.size())/2 times. In addition to that i would still need to scan over the mask to figure out where to slice the vector. This could be even more difficult on matrices.

Comment: When you use `vector(mask_idcs)` later you are also using slicing but an inbuilt one.

Comment: Shouldn't this then be called indexing? I am a bit confused with the terminology. But writing a very own index would simply move the code above to lets say `from_bin_mask` which indeed is more elegant, but not more optimized.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no "out of the shelf" solution using Eigen's methods. However it is interesting to notice that (at least for Eigen versions greater or equal than `3.4.0`), you can using a `std::vector<int>` for indexing (see [this section](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html)). Therefore the code you've written could simplified to

```
Eigen::Array<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> mask = ... // E.G.: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];

std::vector<int> mask_idcs;
for (int z = 0; z < mask.rows(); z++) {
    if (mask(z)) {
        mask_idcs.push_back(z);
    }
}
// do further calculations on vector(mask_idcs)
// E.G.:    vector(mask_idcs)*3 + another_vector
```

If you're using `c++20`, you could use an alternative implementation using `std::ranges` without using raw for-loops:

```
int const N = mask.size();
auto c = iota(0, N) | filter([&mask](auto const& i) { return mask[i]; });
auto masked_indices = std::vector(begin(c), end(c));
// ... Use it as vector(masked_indices) ...
```

I've implemented some minimal examples in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9oTW7PfM6) in case you'd like to check out. I honestly wished there was a simpler way to initialize the `std::vector` from the raw range, but it's currently [not so simple](https://timur.audio/how-to-make-a-container-from-a-c20-range). Therefore I'd suggest you to wrap the code into a helper function, for example

```
auto filtered_indices(auto const& mask) // or as you've suggested from_bin_mask(auto const& mask)
{
    using std::ranges::begin;
    using std::ranges::end;
    using std::views::filter;
    using std::views::iota;

    int const N = mask.size();
    auto c = iota(0, N) | filter([&mask](auto const& i) { return mask[i]; });
    return std::vector(begin(c), end(c));
}
```

and then use it as, for example,

```
Eigen::ArrayXd F(5);
F << 0.0, 1.1548, 0.0, 0.0, 2.333;
auto mask = (F > 1e-15).eval();
auto D = (F(filtered_indices(mask)) + 3).eval();
```

It's not as clean as in `numpy`, but it's something :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way, which seems to be more elegant then comparing each element if it equals to `0`:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<bool> mask_sparse = mask.matrix().sparseView();
for (uint32_t k = 0; k<mask.outerSize(); ++k) {
    for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<bool>::InnerIterator it(mask_sparse, k); it; ++it) {
        std::cout << it.row() << std::endl;   // row index
        std::cout << it.col() << std::endl;   // col index
        // Do Stuff or built up an array
        }
    }
```

Here we can at least build up a vector (or multiple vectors, if we have more dimensions) and then later use it to "mask" a vector or matrix. (This is taken from the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html)).

So applied to this specific usecase, we simply do:

```
Eigen::Array<uint32_t, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> mask_idcs(mask.count(), 1);
Eigen::SparseVector<bool> mask_sparse = mask.matrix().sparseView();
int z_idx = 0;
for (Eigen::SparseVector<bool>::InnerIterator it(mask_sparse); it; ++it) {
    mask_idcs(z_idx++) = it.index()
}

// do Stuff like vector(mask_idcs)*3 + another_vector
```

However, i do not know which version is faster for large masks containing thousands of elements.