# Extract Eigen subarray based on a boolean array

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

I have two `Eigen::VectorXd` named `xl` and `xu` with the same size. Based on these arrays, I build a boolean array `fixed_indices` as follows (Given some tolerance `tol`).

```cpp
Eigen::Vector<bool, Eigen::Dynamic> fixed_indices = (xl - xu).array().abs() <= tol;
```

I want to extract the values of `xl` and `xu` where `fixed_indices` is true. In other words, in the Python world (using NumPy), I would do

```py
fixed_values = 0.5 * (xl[fixed_indices] + xu[fixed_indices])
```

How can I do that with Eigen arrays?
Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More efficient way to get indices of a binary mask in Eigen3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926877/more-efficient-way-to-get-indices-of-a-binary-mask-in-eigen3)

Comment: @chtz Thanks for the comment. Yes and no. This thread basically says that there is no way of doing it currently. I will stick with my `for` loop then...

Comment: If you need to make it as fast as possible, there are ways of doing that but they wouldn't be short or idiomatic. Still I could write an answer for that

Comment: Hi @Homer512. That would be lovely. If I understand correctly, an answer would use visitors, but the documentation is not clear on this mechanism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the baseline that I compare against. All fancy versions like `std::ranges` should compile to similar code, so let's keep it simple.

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXd fixed_values(
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xl,
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xu,
      double tol)
{
  Eigen::Index n = xl.size();
  assert(xu.size() == n);
  Eigen::VectorXd rtrn(n);
  Eigen::Index out = 0;
  for(Eigen::Index i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double xli = xl[i], xui = xu[i];
    if(std::abs(xli - xui) <= tol)
      rtrn[(out++)] = (xli + xui) * 0.5;
  }
  rtrn.conservativeResize(out);
  return rtrn;
}
```

Compile with `-DNDEBUG` to avoid the cost of range checks in the loop. 100,000 calls with 10,000 elements per vector and ca. 5,000 output elements takes 2.4 seconds on my system.

Here is an optimized version.

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXd fixed_values(
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xl,
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xu,
      double tol)
{
  Eigen::Index n = xl.size();
  assert(xu.size() == n);
  Eigen::VectorXd rtrn(n);
  Eigen::Index out = 0;
  for(Eigen::Index i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double xli = xl[i], xui = xu[i];
    rtrn[out] = (xli + xui) * 0.5;
    out += std::abs(xli - xui) <= tol;
  }
  rtrn.conservativeResize(out);
  return rtrn;
}
```

This takes 0.5 seconds in the same benchmark. The trick is to avoid the conditional jump. The redundant memory stores are dirt-cheap in comparison.

This pattern should work as long as the computation is relatively cheap. If it becomes expensive, it may make sense to instead use the same to generate the indices instead.

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXd fixed_values(
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xl,
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xu,
      double tol)
{
  Eigen::Index n = xl.size();
  Eigen::VectorXi indices(n);
  const auto condition = (xl.array() - xu.array()).abs() <= tol;
  Eigen::Index out = 0;
  for(Eigen::Index i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    indices[out] = i;
    out += condition[i];
  }
  auto used = indices.head(out);
  return (xl(used, 0) + xu(used, 0)) * 0.5;
}
```

But don't do this for simple operations such as these above. Case in point: This takes 0.75 seconds.

Side-note: If you don't want to compile with `-DNDEBUG` to keep the assertions active, change the code to work with the raw pointers from `vector.data()` instead.

### Intrinsics

AVX512 comes with a new compress-store instruction that can be used for this. However, I don't think compilers are good at using it, yet. But with some manual work, this can be exploited. I'M using [Intel intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) for this:

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
// using intel intrinsics
#include <cstdint>
// using std::uintptr_t

Eigen::VectorXd fixed_values(
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xl,
      const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& xu,
      double tol)
{
  Eigen::Index n = xl.size();
  assert(xu.size() == n);
  Eigen::VectorXd rtrn(n);
  const double* xlptr = xl.data(), *xuptr = xu.data();
  double* outptr = rtrn.data();
  /*
   * Step 1: Scalar loop until input is aligned with cache-line
   * boundary (=natural alignment of vectors).
   * We do this on the input since the output will be misaligned
   * anyway
   */
  unsigned startbyte = static_cast<unsigned>(
      reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(xlptr));
  unsigned next_aligned = (startbyte + 63) & -64;
  Eigen::Index misaligned = std::min<Eigen::Index>(
      n, (next_aligned - startbyte) / sizeof(double));
  Eigen::Index out = 0;
  Eigen::Index i;
  for(i = 0; i < misaligned; ++i) {
    double xli = xlptr[i], xui = xuptr[i];
    outptr[out] = (xli + xui) * 0.5;
    out += std::abs(xli - xui) <= tol;
  }
  /*
   * Step 2: Vectorized main loop.
   * Might be worth comparing with a loop that uses 256 bit
   * vectors for hardware that doesn't like 512 bit vectors
   */
  const __m512d tol8 = _mm512_set1_pd(tol);
  const __m512d half8 = _mm512_set1_pd(0.5);
  for(; i + 8 <= n; i += 8) {
    __m512d xli = _mm512_load_pd(xlptr + i);
    __m512d xui = _mm512_loadu_pd(xuptr + i);
    __m512d diff = _mm512_sub_pd(xli, xui);
    __m512d absdiff = _mm512_abs_pd(diff);
    __mmask8 mask = _mm512_cmp_pd_mask(absdiff, tol8, _CMP_LE_OQ);
    __m512d sum = _mm512_add_pd(xli, xui);
    __m512d mean = _mm512_mul_pd(sum, half8);
    _mm512_mask_compressstoreu_pd(outptr + out, mask, mean);
    unsigned imask = _cvtmask8_u32(mask);
    out += _mm_popcnt_u32(imask);
  }
  /*
   * Step 3: Scalar loop for last 0-7 elements
   */
  for(; i < n; ++i) {
    double xli = xlptr[i], xui = xuptr[i];
    outptr[out] = (xli + xui) * 0.5;
    out += std::abs(xli - xui) <= tol;
  }
  rtrn.conservativeResize(out);
  return rtrn;
}
```

This runs in 0.166 seconds on my system.

Comment: That is a lovely answer; thank you very much! The final version of the code should not be architecture-dependent, and the dimension of the bound vectors should be reasonable. Since I need to extract the values of the fixed indices but also other values based on the same boolean array, I will stick with the "`np.flatnonzero`" solution (the second one), as I will be able to reuse this `indices` array in the remainder of the code. Again, thank you!